# Better handling of large legends in Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Tags: feature-request, bug, data-explorer

## The problem

[image: screenshot]

The legend on Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE), keeps going on, below the bottom of the page, on a white background, breaking the page (I've cropped this out to keep the page from being needlessly long).

## Example

An example can be found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/850357/1050015/my-tags#graph)

## Ways this could be fixed

- Option to extract the legend to a table

  This would allow for multiple columns
- Scrollable legend

  It could stay in the same space without breaking the page
- The option to remove the legend

  This would allow for a mode that is nearer to a line graph, with no legend

Comment: Even if there was just a way to disable the legend it would be helpful